# Could someone explain the proof of this theorem to me?

Tags: proof-explanation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWyJX.jpg)Hello, I’m new to math and I consider myself a hobbyist. Could someone explain the type of proof this is and how it works? I can see that it appeared to be a proof by contradiction but I don’t understand where the integration is coming from. The theorem relates to the two cycle solutions of difference equations. Picture is uploaded.

Comment: Since $f'$ is continuous in the (I assume compact) interval $I$, it is integrable, so for the fundamental theorem of calculus it is $f(b)-f(a)=\int_a^b f'(x) \text{d}x$. Of course it is $\int_a^b 1 \text{d}x=b-a$. For the future questions, please don't upload pictures for such short statements and please show us your efforts to solve the problem. Thank you.

Comment: I believe, proof is clear. $1+f' 0$ and $f'$ is continuous $\Rightarrow 1+f'$ is always positive or always negative in $I$, then integral of $1+f'$ is not zero. Then use fundamental theorem of calculus to find integral value in case $x_1\neq x_0$.

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34121/42969). Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof does not *need* to use integration. In fact, I would find the following proof more natural.

---

Suppose there is a 2-cycle, i.e. $x,y\in I$ such that $x\ne y$ and $f(x)=y, f(y)=x$. Per Mean Value Theorem, there is a $\xi$ between $x$ and $y$ such that:

$$f'(\xi)=\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}=\frac{x-y}{y-x}=-1$$

... but this is a contradiction, because it implies $f'(\xi)+1=0$.

---

I believe the original proof is a variant of this (there is such a thing as a Mean Value Theorem for integrals), but it obscures the basic idea a bit. Which (the basic idea) is: if the points $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$ are swapped, the "chord" on the function graph joining those points has the slope (gradient) $-1$ and so there must be a point in between with a tangent which also has gradient $-1$.

Comment: Thanks, this is much more clear.